# How to set the executable name in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I tried using `set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "...")`, but that only specifies the directory where the executable is created. I also need to change the name of the executable itself. How can I do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Have you tried using [SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_target_properties.html?highlight=set_target_properties) and using the [OUTPUT_NAME](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html?highlight=output_name) property?

Answer (score 64):

Put the following statement after the target is defined (i.e. after the `add_executable` or `add_library`)

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "your name")
```

See the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html) for more details.